# Condition parameter type does not match schema type AWS DynamoDB Query with nestjs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, nestjs, dynamodb-queries

I do query in aws cli to get DynamoDB data

```
aws dynamodb query \
--table-name video \
--key-condition-expression  "id = :id" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":id":{"N": "7"}}'
```

and it works

However,
I do the same query in nestjs code it failed

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  region: 'us-east-1',
});

public async getVideoById(id:number){

     const params = {
        TableName: "video",
        KeyConditionExpression: "id = :ID",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":ID": id
        }
      }
 
      return await ddb.query(params).promise()
      .then(data => data.Items);
   }
```

it return

> [ExceptionsHandler] One or more parameter values were invalid:
> Condition parameter type does not match schema type

Comment: It sounds like there's a type mismatch for the `id` value. Try hardcoding `7` in place of the `id` value when creating the params, does that work? If so then you know that's the problem.

Comment: thanks it fixes my problem